# Search a query that matches multiple table fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to retrieve / output values that match multiple table fields.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name IN ( 'Value1', 'Value2' );
```

My search query should take the following parameters : first_name and roll_number in user_table.

e.g. Retrieving a query on the following lines : Roy whose roll number is 5

I need to query this using a single query.

Comment: `where (First_Name, Roll_Number) in ('Roy',5)`  I think this is called a paired value in operator

Comment: You could use full text searching, that indexes multiple columns then you search your term against the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing the following sql statement:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE first_name IN ('Roy') AND roll_number = 5;
```

You can alternatively try the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE first_name = 'Roy' AND roll_number = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from tableName 
where roll_number =5
and first_name ='ROY'
```

--replace 5 and ROY with parameter